# Vite 4 build files without hash

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am using Vite 4.2.0 for my react project. I want my build files name without hash.
I have tried below config in vite.config.js but still it's not reflecting.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build:{
    rollupOutputOptions: {
      entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
      chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
      assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
    },
    css: {
      extract: {
        filename: '[name].css' // change CSS file name to include hash
      }
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use hash?

Comment: I want to host build files and add them as CDN to some other project. If it has hash then file name keeps changing.

Comment: Can you add the result from the code above?

Comment: Can you try to change `rollupOutputOptions` to `rollupOptions`?

Comment: Hi, I tried `rollupOptions` but it shows a kind of warning like.
Unknown input options: entryFileNames, chunkFileNames, assetFileNames. Allowed options: acorn, acornInjectPlugins, cache, context, experimentalCacheExpiry, experimentalLogSideEffects...

also, the output is as same as the default.

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/378#issuecomment-768816653

Comment: Can you try this issue solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The config is named [`build.rollupOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-rollupoptions), but you've incorrectly entered `build.rollupOutputOptions`. Also remember to use [Rollup's `output` option](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-entryfilenames) within that:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-custom-output-filenames)

Answer (score 0):

This can solve the purpose. Complete vite.config.js will look something like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

 export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
    vue({
        template: {
            transformAssetUrls: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false,
            },
        },
    }),
    laravel({
        input: [
            'resources/css/app.css', 
            'resources/js/app.js',
            'resources/assets/frontend/frontend.css',
            'resources/assets/backend/frontend.css'
        ],
        refresh: true
    }),
],
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].css',
      }
    }
  }
});
```